# POST Route to END Route

Tags: node.js, rest, express, post, handlebars.js

I am building a Node.JS website and need to change my current GET Route to POST route. How do I successfully make the conversion. My current error is 'Cannot GET /' Then I need to have the POST Route hit the GET route.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const hbs = require('express-handlebars');

// Moment.js
var moment = require('moment');

// Init App
const app = express();

// Json File
const json = require("./data.json");

// Javascript Files
const welcomeTime = require('./public/javascript/welcomeTime');

// Load View Engine
app.engine('hbs', hbs({extname: 'hbs', defaultLayout: 'layout', 
layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts/'}));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));

// GET Route
// app.get('/', function(req, res){
//     res.render('index', {
//         title: 'NodePark',
//         hotel: 'NodePark',
//         firstName: json.payload.data.Source_FirstName,
//         lastname: json.payload.data.Source_LastName,
//         date: moment().format('ll'),
//         time: moment().format('LT'),
//         currentHour: welcomeTime.dayTime()
//     });
// });

// POST Route
app.post('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'NodePark',
        hotel: 'NodePark',
        firstName: json.payload.data.Source_FirstName,
        lastname: json.payload.data.Source_LastName,
        date: moment().format('ll'),
        time: moment().format('LT'),
        currentHour: welcomeTime.dayTime()
    });
});

// Start Server
app.listen(5000, function(){
    console.log('Port 5000 open for business.');
});
```

I have included my working GET Route and an attempt at the POST Route. I do not understand why it is not working.

layout.hbs is below

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fanwood+Text:400i" rel="stylesheet">        
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
    <style>li span { position: relative; left: -8px; }</style>
</head>
<body>
    {{{ body }}}
</body>
</html>
```

index.hbs is below

```
    <div id="body-container">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo-content">
            <div id="logo"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="welcome">
            <p>Good {{ currentHour }} {{ firstName }} {{ lastname }}. We hope your stay is comfortable & relaxing.</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        {{!-- <div id="time-side">
            <div id="time-content">
                <p> {{ date }} <br> {{ time }} </p>
            </div>
        </div> --}}
    </div> 
    {{!-- end of header --}}

    <div id="background">
        <img src="images/villaView.jpg" alt="villaView">
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <p> <br> &copy; 2018 NodePark </p>
    </div>
```

My goal is to create an endpoint in which goes from POST route to GET route.

Comment: So you want to transform the incoming request from a POST to a GET?

Comment: Specifically I need a POST to a GET for IoT. I guess it is tranfsorming request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your post handler, call `res.redirect("<new-url>")` to redirect the user to `<new-url>`.

```
// POST Route
app.post('/', function(req, res){
    // store the incoming data somewhere, e.g. in a cookie-based session
    res.redirect('/');
});

// GET Route
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    // retrieve the posted data from somewhere, e.g. from a cookie-based session
    res.render('index', { ... });
});
```

Comment: Wouldn’t it still be a POST though?

Comment: The user said "need to change my current GET Route to POST route", so I was assuming he wanted to make a POST request first and then get redirected to the same page to go through the GET handler. Perhaps I misunderstood?

Comment: Also, the last bit of the question: "My goal is to create an endpoint in which goes from POST route to GET route." is probably what confused me.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. For my IoT services to work I need a POST route first. You were correct initially, I need a POST to a GET route.

Comment: I'm spinning up a little express project now to test some stuff, but can you just be super clear what you mean by "POST to a GET"? Are you sending a payload to the POST? What will happen to it when it reaches the GET? Why do you even need GET anyway? Can't you just return info from the POST request?

Comment: Initially thats what I figured would be better, return info from POST request. But my partner said he needs a POST route to a GET route for the IOT service to function properly. Which do you think would be better?

Comment: Well Petr's code does indeed work. I didn't find any documentation on why res.redirect transforms the request into a GET, but it does, so that should be perfect for your use case.

Comment: Yeah, I believe the redirection uses GET by default: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: @FreshOceans glad we figured it out together :) Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @PetrBroz for the links, it looks like express will not alter the method when you specify a 307, but for all others (including 308) it will change to a GET. when I put `res.redirect(307, '/')` in my post handler, it looped through the callback handler 11 times then stopped without sending anything to the requester (timeout). TIL...